# Google Maps sdk mylocationenable shows other image

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

When i enable the current location on google maps in ios, the i get an image of J and U on the map at the point of my location. Screen shot attached.[image]

Comment: I think you have missed used other icon instead of current location icon

Comment: @vinayManeti, I have not used any icon for current location. This image is what appears as i enable it on my map.